# how does entity framework save auto increment ids

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i am a bit weary about how does EF saves related tables with auto increment primary key which are foreign keys to other tables for example this two related tables:

```
public partial class LoanType
{
    public LoanType()
    {
        this.Loans = new HashSet<Loan>();
    }

    public int loan_type_id { get; set; }
    public string loan_type_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}

public partial class Loan
{
    public Loan()
    {
        this.Collections = new HashSet<Collection>();
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int loan_id { get; set; }
    public int loan_type_id { get; set; }
    public int emp_id { get; set; }
    public int voucher_id { get; set; }
    public int term_id { get; set; }
    public int comaker_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime loan_date_added { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public virtual Comaker Comaker { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual LoanType LoanType { get; set; }
    public virtual Term Term { get; set; }
    public virtual Voucher Voucher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

they are related via loan type id which is a auto increment fields. would EF will know if what is the id save if i generate both new entities such as

```
LoanType LT = new LoanType();

//assign new values

Loan loan = new Loan();

//assign values for loan

context.SaveChanges();
```

would EF know what will be the id of the new loan type and will link it to newly created loan??

Comment: Have you even *tried it* yourself?!?!? **YES**, EF will know! If you have a new `Loan` and you assign it a new `LoadType` entity, and save the data - EF will know that those two entities are linked, and it **will** update the `LoanTypeID` in the `Loan` object for you - automagically!

Comment: @marc_s It just popped up on my mind just a will ago while surfing for database first.. Thanks. i will try it